# Storing multiple URLs in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm building a database of products and wondering how I should store product image URLs in my product rows (some products have single image URLs, others have multiple).

Are there drawbacks to creating a separate column for each specific image URL? Would it possible to store multiple URLs in a single column (as an array?) and if so, is that advantageous?

Answer (score 4):

I would create a table called product_images whose structure will be simple and will be joined with your products table something on the lines of this:

```
create table product_images (
   id serial primary key,
   product_id int not null references products(id),
   url text not null
);
```

That way if you choose to add images instead of URLs in the database, this structure can be morphed accordingly without having to affect your products table.

Example:

```
create table products (
  id serial primary key,
  name varchar(100)
);

create table product_images (
  id serial primary key,
   product_id int not null references products(id),
   url text not null
);

insert into products (name) values ('iPad'), ('Surface Pro');
insert into product_images (product_id, url) values 
('1', 'http://apple.com'),
('1', 'http://buy.apple.com'),
('2', 'http://microsoft.com'),
('2', 'http://msdn.microsoft.com');
```

Comment: Thanks @zedfoxus - in the separate product_image table, would you create a column for each separate URL? Would you try and store them as an array (see answer below)?

Comment: I have added an example of how I would store them (one url per row).

Comment: When fetching a product, how could we get all those images? I tried, and getting multiple rows for a single product.

Comment: @Tom, if your database stores only 1 image per product then you will get just one image back. If your database stores 2+ images per product, then you have to decide whether which one you want, or whether you want all of the images. It depends on your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I might opt for just having an array of URLs for each link to an image, something like this would work:

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
   id integer,
   image_url text[]
);
```

Comment: Thanks @CraigKerstiens - I wondered that too, but at the top of the postgres documentation on arrays it seems to indicate that domains are not supported. I'm not sure if that's strictly true? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html